# Background-image problem in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have anchor element with CSS class.
All browser show the BG-image well, except IE 7 (it won't show the image at all). (I added the _attributes since I saw thats what is used in other sites).
When using IE Developr tools in IE7 it says background-image: none... Thanks

```
color: #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
height: 102px;
left: 0;
margin-left: -7px;    
position: fixed;
text-indent: -9999px;
top: 25%;
width: 35px;
z-index: 9998;
background-color: #279cff;
border-color: #279cff;
border-style: outset outset outset none;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:170px;     
background-image: url(../images/1.png);     
background-position: 11px;
```

Comment: Do you mean opacity in png files ?

Comment: :) - I wish... anyhow IE7 won't work either

Comment: @Sanja - The image won't show at all

Comment: @Jason: I totally agree!!! Not even MS support it anymore!!

Comment: if all developers refuse to support IE6, maybe we can all live happily lives :)

Comment: give us the link if any?

Comment: this can be useful http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Answer (score 0):

If your starting with `_property` it is for IE6 hacking. It will work only IE6. For IE6 use `_property` for IE7 use `#property`

Comment: Thats not my problem. it won't show at all. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If the background has alpha transparency you won't be able to see that in IE6 properly because it doesn't render PNGs well. Either switch to gifs OR stop supporting ie6 :P

Comment: Thats not my problem. it won't show at all. I edited my question

Comment: it happens in IE7 ... thats my main concern

Comment: try background: url(../images/1.png) no-repeat;

Comment: also, your position fixed might also be a problem for IE7 if you're not using strict mode

Comment: means, ie7 supports position: fixed but it has to be strict mode(in the doctype)

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is a hack for CSS attribute to work only on 6, don't use it but use different CSS for IE.
IE6 doesn't handle very well with png. try to use jpg and it will probably work.
If not, try to float or display: block the element to see if it shows the background.

Comment: I saw that you edited your question, try using:
background-image:url("../images/1.png");
and put the background-repeat below background-image.